# AHK: very simple script using AltGr not working

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to remap the ñ key to work like `AltGr+4` to produce the tilde (~) sign on the Spanish keyboard.

I made a very simple script:

```
ñ::
send <^>!4
```

When I hit the ñ I get a bip sound and it writes < instead.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this setting:

```
ñ::Send `~
```

Alternatively (I can't test this since I use a US layout and AltGr+4 just beeps), you can try:

```
ñ::Send, {RAlt Down}4{RAlt Up}
```

success

Answer (score 0):

Why not just output the ~ directly?

```
ñ::send, ~
```